# LINQ in EF fails when searching for null values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following code.

```
//I pick the first story where its StartSegment is not null.
var story = container.StorySet.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartSegment != null);

if (story != null)
{

     //the following assert fails because story.StartSegment is null.
     Assert.IsNotNull(story.StartSegment,
                                         "The target story of this homework has no start segment.");

}
```

This unit-test fails, because story.StartSegment is in fact null, but given the FirstOrDefault lambda expression which explicitly searches for stories where the start segment **isn't null**, I don't think this makes any sense.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` in this case

Comment: But why? Can you explain why this is needed? What's the difference?

Comment: First or deafult returns null if no elements were found, you need to check for that.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns default (`null` for classes) value. `First` throws an exception when no matching element is found. You do not seem to handle `default` case here, so you should use `First` to indicate that something really should be found.

Comment: The problem is that the story's StartSegment is null. Not the story itself. So what you are saying isn't needed. The assert fails. I don't get a null-reference exception.

Comment: I modified the code. It should help you understand that it's still not the problem.

Comment: Could you be hitting the issue "Incorrect handling of null variables in 'where' clause" from http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title#suggestion-1015361 ?  The fix is disabled in ObjectContext mode by default so maybe you need to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's lazy/eager load ploblem.

in fact Story.StartSegment is not null.

but you didn't include it (by eager load). try this..

```
var story = container.StorySet
    .Include("StartSegment ")
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartSegment != null);
```

assume that your entitie relation like this..

**StorySet** (many) ----- (0 or 1) **StartSegment**

StartSegment defined as **"NavigationProperty"** of StorySet. and your generated query look like

```
SELECT * FROM StorySet WHERE StorySet.StartSegmentId is not null
```

this query return some existing entity. **but by default EF will not create instant of Navigation Property until you explicitly tell it to** .Include("StartSegment")

Comment: How can I prevent this so that I don't need to use "Include" every time?

Comment: that's default EF behaviors see eager/lazy/explicite loading in  Querying Related Entity Objects [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)

Comment: Did you take a look at the issued SQL statements (sql profiler)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var story = container.StorySet.Where(s => s.StartSegment != null).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Let me just format your message for you, to make it use a code-region.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's DB bool logic related issue. In SQL this is not true: `someNullValue = NULL`. Instead you should use `someNullValue IS NULL`. Probably EF doesn't care about correct null comparison in this case, so it just returns the first element, which might have null `StartSegment`. Check the query that it is issued to the database. It should have `IS NULL` predicate, not something like `= NULL`

Comment: And what's the solution to this problem then? How can I do a proper null comparison?

Comment: Look at the issued SQL command (profiler or in the debugger)!
Is your unit test LINQ to Entities or LINQ to object?